# Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, exception, package

I have imported the necessary file( PeriodList Class) to my (Interface) class, but when I run the program I faced with the Exception :

**Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Interface/PeriodList**

The **PeriodList  class** is in the  **Interface** package and the *Interface  class* is in 
**com.jtattoo.sample**

here is the code:

```
    package com.jtattoo.sample;

    import Interface.PeriodList;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Interface 
    {

     .
     .
     .
     public  static  void  displays(int s)
     { 

       PeriodList pe=new PeriodList();



     }
  }
```

The thing that makes me wonder is that:in the line `PeriodList pe=new PeriodList();`
there is no error which means the **PeriodList class** is clear for the Netbeans and the problem occurs  after  running the project.

Comment: as I know interface can't contain methods with body

Answer (score -2):

1. Why do you name your class as 'Interface'. It's very much confusing.
2. Are you sure the Interface.PeriodList is the correct class name? 
   To import classes in different packages, use

   import package.package...package.ClassName;

Comment: The interface class is responsible to change the Interface of application so i called it interface but **it is a class**

I used "Fixed imports".